# jquery paging issue with IE7

Tags: jquery

I am using a JQUERY plug-in for paging:

```
 http://jonpauldavies.github.com/JQuery/Pager/PagerDemo.html
```

I have created one .js file called inilization.js and below is total code in inilization.js:

```
function init(a,b)
{
$("#pager").pager({ pagenumber: a, pagecount: b, buttonClickCallback: PageClick });
}
```

When I call the page from jquery LOAD

```
   $('#divbody').load('abc.php?pid=1', null, function() {
   init(1,5)
   });
```

this works fine with Firefox but not with internet explorer, I get an error in internet explorer 7:

```
    PageClick is undefined
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did you add 'java' tag for that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `PageClick` callback somewhere.

```
function init(a,b)
{
    $("#pager").pager({ 
        pagenumber: a, 
        pagecount: b, 
        buttonClickCallback: function(pageclickednumber) {
            init(pageclickednumber, b);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: worked but i change the function little bit

         init(pageclickednumber, b,c);
 $('#divbody1').load("abc.php?pid="+c+"&page=" + pageclickednumber);

is this correct approach...?